# How to install Wordpress theme and configure it?

Tags: themes

how to add and configure wordpress theme?can any one help me out with it please?

I installed wamp server,and now I don't know what to do?

Comment: before posting here try yourslef take help of google and wordpress codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Themes

Comment: have a read of this documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Themes

Answer (score 1):

In your Dashboard go to Design > Theme > Tab: Install Themes and then search a theme in the build-in theme browser. Or search the web for premium or free themes first, purchase or free download a theme an upload it as a zip file (that also can be done in your Dashboard).

And honestly, there are a thousand documentations out there you'll find via Google.